# Monitoring Keyboard Only Behavior

Tags: accessibility, keyboard-events

You can pretty easily monitor mouse activity with something like - http://www.labsmedia.com/clickheat/index.html

But how would one monitor the keyboard activity of keyboard only users?  I'd like to learn more how keyboard only users are interacting with megamenus and I'd like to know if they are able to intuitively learn a new behavior (switching between tab & arrow keys) or whether they default to a keyboard mouse solution.

Figuring out the behavior of users is tricky at the best of times, so I'm hoping someone's got some ideas for how to determine the actual usage of the users.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a javascript that catches all keyboard entries, stores these entry's in an array and does an submit when you leave the page..

You can find more info about key logging on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging

Form grabbing based: Form grabbing-based keyloggers log web form submissions by recording the web browsing onsubmit event functions. This records form data before it is passed over the Internet and bypasses HTTPS encryption.

Comment: That makes it look so creepy. But ya, guess it's the same kinda technology that would be used to grab someone's password.  I'm only interested in navigation patterns though.  

Anyways, useful link, so thanks.